# MVC3 (Razor) Json Get deserialized data in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor, stringify, jsonserializer

I need help again with Asp.Net MVC (Razor View Engine).
In my View (Index) I have

```
@model IEnumerable<Movie>
```

I want to pass the Model to the Controller: I stringify the model in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postData(){
var urlact='@Url.Action("createDoc")';
var model ='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    type:"POST",
    url:urlact, 
    datatype:"json",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
}
</script>
```

Everything seems to work, cause I know the stringified data is:

```
'[{"ID":1,"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1007938800000)\/","Genre":"Fantasy","Price":93000000.00},{"ID":2,"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1039042800000)\/","Genre":"Fantasy","Price":94000000.00},{"ID":3,"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1070233200000)\/","Genre":"Fantasy","Price":94000000.00}]';
```

The problem is: in Controller, methodName *"createDoc"* (as declared in the script) I cannot access to the stringified data.
Following some samples founded on the web, my method is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createDoc(IEnumerable<Movie> movies)
    {
        //...using movies list
        return View();
    }
```

Why can't I access to the stringified data? How can I do it, is there some method to call to deserialize the model in the Controller method?
Also, can I use the serialize() method instead of the stringify() one? If so, what's the syntax, View & Controller side?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Is the movies parameter null? Does it throw an error at all?

Comment: No, I simply can't do anything on my createDoc action. Seems like nothing is posted to it. (I don't know, maybe the declaration for the input parameter is wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got stringified data in your JavaScript variable `model`. You only need to call `JSON.stringify` on objects which aren't strings.

If you want to post the data to your action without modifying `model`, just pass in `model` without the `JSON.stringify` and the ModelBinder will take care of deserializing it to `IEnumerable<Movie>` for you.

If you want to use `model` as something other than a string, you'll want to call `JSON.parse` on the string. In other words:

```
var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
```

Then, you'd want to keep your `JSON.stringify` call.

Finally, `stringify` is a method on a browser-specific object `JSON`, whereas `serialize` is a method on the ASP.NET MVC-specific `Json` object. Two different worlds, same name.

Comment: Is not necessary use the JSON.parse in this case because the HTML.Raw already will return the raw json. So just do this: `var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');`

Comment: This is good except you need to escape any single quotes `'` in your json string. `JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model).Replace("'", "\\'"))');`